# Z-label does not show up in 3d matplotlib scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter3d

The z-label does not show up in my figure. What is wrong?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("y")
ax.set_zlabel("z")
plt.show()
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFtnt.png)

Neither `ax.set_zlabel("z")` nor `ax.set(zlabel="z")` works. The x- and y-labels work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a *padding* issue.

> labelpadfloat The distance between the axis label and the tick labels.
> Defaults to `rcParams["axes.labelpad"]` **(default: 4.0)** = 4.

You can use [`matplotlib.axis.ZAxis.labelpad`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axis_api.html#matplotlib.axis.ZAxis.labelpad) to adjust this value for the z-axis :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("y")
ax.set_zlabel("StackOverflow", rotation=90)
ax.zaxis.labelpad=-0.7 # <- change the value here
plt.show();
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: I find this a bit unsettling. There is so much space on the left-hand side of the figure. It is not clear to me, why can we simply put the whole figure a bit to the left.